# Traefik ACME DNS challenge not working with docker

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm trying to configure Traefik as a proxy for docker containers running on DigitalOcean servers.

Here's my Traefik container configuration:

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
    environment:
      DO_AUTH_TOKEN: abcd
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.example.com
      - traefik.port=8080

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

And traefik.toml,

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  users = ["admin:secretpassword"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
[acme]
email = "lakshmi@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
onDemand = false
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
    provider = "digitalocean"
    delayBeforeCheck = 0
```

When I try to access https://monitor.example.com, I get this error:

```
traefik    | time="2018-05-29T15:35:32Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"monitor.example.com\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:monitor.example.com\" : cannot obtain certificates: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[monitor.example.com] Error presenting token: HTTP 403: forbidden: You do not have access for the attempted action.\n"
```

I have given a valid DO token and pointed monitor.example.com to the VM running Traefik. Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting a 403 because Traefik was trying to write a TXT entry for ACME DNS challenge in my DigitalOcean domain using a `read-only` token. I changed it to a `read-write` token and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm I am having the same issue and I am not seeing a way to to change to read-write.  I don't see any setting for it.

Comment: @badri, Can you point me to a resource that shows how to configure the digitalocean DNS challenge? The digitalocean example on their website uses tls challenge. The docker-compose.yml files I can find do not have the token in them, so I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, make sure acme.json has 600 permissions. Don't create or touch acme.json yourself. Let Traefik create it. After the pod is created, check permissions on acme.json.
The problem I found is Traefik creates acme.json and sets it to 600. After running upgrade, acme.json changed to 660 and starting giving the 'unknown resolver letsencrypt' error. The fix was having to uncomment the 'initContainers' lines in the values.yml in the Traefik Helm chart. Basically it sets permissions to 600 before startup. Hacky but works.

```yaml
deployment:
  enabled: true
  # Can be either Deployment or DaemonSet
  kind: Deployment
  replicas: 1
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  podAnnotations: {}
  podLabels: {}
  additionalContainers: []
  volumeMounts:
    - name: csi-pvc 
  initContainers: 
    - name: volume-permissions
      image: busybox:1.31.1
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chmod -Rv 600 /data/*"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: csi-pvc
          mountPath: /data
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  imagePullSecrets: []
```